# how to login as admin user or reset admin user password when laptop keypad and external keyboard is not working

Tags: permissions, root

in my laptop keypad and external keyboard is not working. how to login in admin account from guest or any other way. Actually i want to take backup of my data.

Comment: It might be a bit far fetched, but it should be possible to use a bootable USB, configure SSH access, and then access it from another computer, where the keyboard works.

Comment: he can try `sudo su` to be connected as root, and then, give permissions or save data on an USB devices

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple, just use the onscreen keyboard & mouse. In unity greeter rather obvious, click on the accessibility icon in greeter panel, ect.

In the currrent 18.04 gdm (gnome-shell) greeter click on the  accessibility icon > enable the onscreen keyboard, then pull it up from bottom of the screen with mouse.